# intersect with ST_Buffer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, query, pgadmin

I have a table called "gebaeude" with all types of buildings in the city.
In the following I want to use a Buffer around the central train station that has the id="2" and a radius of 1000m. Then I want to select the building types "kinergarten" and "school" that are within this radius by intersecting them with the buffer. What I did looks like this:

```
WITH center AS (
     SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 1000) FROM gebaeude 
     WHERE id='2')
SELECT gebaeude.name AS "Name",
        ST_Distance(center.geom, gebaeude) AS Distanz
FROM gebaeude, center
WHERE (gebaeude='school' OR gebaeude.type='kindergarten')
AND ST_Intersects(gebaeude.geom,center.geom);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  column center.geom does not exist
> LINE 5: ST_Distance(center.geom, gebaeude) AS Distanz
> ^

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do *not* do that. This is one of the most infamous misconceptions in spatial computation. You got an answer using `ST_DWithin`  on one of your older posts, and that is the optimal solution!

Comment: This isn't really a GIS error or PostGIS issue so much as a PostgreSQL/database one, so you probably want to research in [dba.se] as well. The moral of the story here is to *always* alias function/expression-based columns (so you don't have to memorize how the unnamed field is mapped according to rules in the DBMS).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify column names in the CTE, they will have the same names as in the inner select statement, so here the column would be named `st_buffer` instead of `geom`.

You can set the name at the CTE level

```sql
WITH center(geom) AS (
     SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 1000) ...
)
```

or within the inner select:

```sql
WITH center AS (
     SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 1000) as geom ...
)
```

But really, don't use a buffer here, it is not the way to go with your issue. Use `ST_DWithin` instead.